# Passing parameters with an Action link on an image

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have been looking everywhere for this answer. I can't find any solution. I am using MVC3 ASP.NET. I am trying to make it so that when a user clicks on their profile it directs them to their profile using their id. So far nothing has worked.

```
<a href=@Html.ActionLink("", 
  "Profile", 
  "Followers", 
  new { id = (new UserService().GetUserByUserName(User.Identity.Name)).Id})>
    <img src="blah.jpg" />
</a>
```

This does not seem to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Html.ActionLink` returns a complete `<a>` tag, not a URL.

You want to call `Url.Action`.